# Jest matcher toMatchObject works with Array, fails with a subclass of Array

Tags: arrays, jestjs, subclass, matcher

In the following simple test, the first assertion passes, the second fails:

```
class MyArray<T> extends Array<T> {
  constructor(private _id: string, ...a: T[]) {
    super(...a);
  }
}

describe('Test MyArray', () => {
  fit('Should create an array of strings', () => {
    const baseArray = new Array<string>('One', 'Two');
    const subbedArray = new MyArray<string>('the_array', 'One', 'Two');
    expect(baseArray).toMatchObject(['One', 'Two']);
    expect(subbedArray).toMatchObject(['One', 'Two']);
  });
});
```

Presumably the failure is due to the addition of the private field.  The failure message is:

```
Expected ["One", "Two"], got serializes to the same string
```

Is there a way around this?  Is there a different sub-classing technique to be used?

Comment: Yes, it's the additional field - to compare objects, it compares the values for _all_ of their properties. If you want to use the subclass, you'd have to change the assertion.